# Why does this code need semicolons at the beginning

Tags: c

I know that I need semicolons at the end of an instruction,
but when I tried to compile, it asked me for semicolons at places that I do not know why and it works but **the question now is why did I need semicolons at the beginning of a while loop and before the closing bracket**?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int     main()
{
    char a = 'a'
    ;while (a <= 'z')
    {
        write(1, &a, 1);
        a++;
    }    
    return (0)
;}
```

but I didn't need semicolons here in this code (not before anything atleast)

```
#include <unistd.h>

char    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

char    rec(char a)
{
    if (a <= 'z')
    {
        ft_putchar(a);
        a++;
        rec(a);
    }
    return (0);
}

int     main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    rec(a);
    return (0);
}
```

I am running on windows 10 visual studio code.

Comment: The semicolon terminates the statement preceding the loop; it doesn't start the loop statement.

Comment: C error reporting is a bit imprecise.  It reports an error when it detects it, which is at the beginning of the next statement.  As @GovindParmar says, these semicolons are for the previous line, but newlines don't mean anything to the C parser.

Comment: C is a very free-form language. White-space (newlines, tabs, spaces, etc.) doesn't matter in most contexts. That means you can place the terminating semicolon almost anywhere, including on the next line before the next statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply forgot the semicolons at the end of the previous line, and fixed it by putting it at the beginning of the next line.

C doesn't actually care about where your semicolons are, as long as they are between statements; It doesn't care where new lines are:

Your code here

```
#include <unistd.h>

int     main()
{
    char a = 'a'
    ;while (a <= 'z')
    {
        write(1, &a, 1);
        a++;
    }    
    return (0)
;}
```

is the same as

```
#include <unistd.h>

int     main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    while (a <= 'z')
    {
        write(1, &a, 1);
        a++;
    }    
    return (0);
}
```

and is also the same as:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() { char a = 'a'; while (a <= 'z') {write(1, &a, 1); a++; } return (0);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not wrong but has just a very unusual formatting. Normally you put the line breaks *after* the `;` and not before.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 'a';

    while (a <= 'z')
    {
        write(1, &a, 1);
        a++;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

BTW: you should not put the return values between () like you did here `return (0);` but you should write simply `return 0;`. Putting () is not wrong, but unnecessary nd it makes it look like a function call.

Line breaks are not necessary for a C program you could write this and it would compile:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {char a = 'a';while (a <= 'z'){
write(1, &a, 1);a++;} return 0;}
```

This code snippet, my previous code snippet and *your* code snippet are equivalent.

Comment: i know but the problem was that that didnt work and now it does(with those semicolons at the beginning)

Comment: @MC it's not clear what did not work. You should edit your question and make that clear.

Comment: @MC The compiler told you it wanted a semicolon; it's up to you whether you put that before the next statement, or after the previous statement.  It's all the same to the C compiler.  Jabberwocky's code and yours are the exact same.  Lines aren't required at all.

Comment: @jabberwocky the problem was that it did work and i didnt know why

Comment: @MC well you need to show us _what exactly_ didn't work, and show us the verbatim error messages from the compiler  if any. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: no i know it now but i needed to wait before i could accept an answer